# ASP.NET: Search inside treeview nodes

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I have a treeview with some nodes

```
--Parent
  --Child-0
    --child-0.0
    --child-0.1
    --child-0.2
    --child-0.3
  --Child-1
  --Child-2
```

I am updating this treeview later on, how can u update/insert values into `child-0.2` programmatically where i don't know how many child does `Child-0` has?

Tried following code, but compiler doesn't like it

```
foreach (TreeNode n in Treeview1.Nodes[0].ChildNodes[0])
{
   //whats the syntax gonna be?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int childrenCount = Treeview1.Nodes[0].ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes.Count;
```